# Differentiating from WhittakerM function and substitution

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I'm trying to differentiate WhittakerM function. 
To solve the WhittakerM  equation we have:

```
dsolve( 'D2y+(-1/4+Landa/r+(1/4-(L+1/2)^2)/r^2)*y=0' ,'r')

C1*WhittakerM(Landa,L+1/2,r)+C2*WhittakerW(Landa,L+1/2,r)
```

from the boundary condition I only need `WhittakerM(Landa,L+1/2,r)/r`that `1/r`is added for the condition of the problem. I'm trying to defferentiate it then substitute in some points, but there are some errorin `subs`and `diff`.

```
Landa=1;L=0; % # for simplicity
R1=inline('WhittakerM(Landa,L+1/2,r)/r','r');
Rp1=diff(R1,r);
r=1:0.01:20;
R1sub=eval(R1,r);
Rp1sub=eval(Rp1,r);
```

Do u have any idea?

Comment: You are substituting `r` with `x` but `x` is not defined. You have to define `x`. I don't get the porpose of substituting r with x, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited. I just want to evaluate the function and have a numerical array.

Comment: Is `landa` the same as `Landa`? Why are you plugging in numbers before taking the derivative? And if there's an error message you should edit your question to add the entire message.

Comment: @horchler: Erroe messages added.

Comment: I just want to know how can I differentiate this clumsy function and evaluate it in some arbitrary points regardless of any other details.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the errors above (honestly I do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve with the substitution), using the symbolic toolbox might be a good start here:

```
syms r
%defines a symbolic function
R1(r)=whittakerM(landa,l+1/2,r)/r
%differentiate
Rp1=diff(R1,r);
%evaluate
Rp1_e=Rp1(1:0.01:20)
```

Comment: Are u sure? Undefined function or method `WhittakerM` for input arguments of type `sym`.

Comment: for evaluation `eval` is a proper choice and compatible with `sym`. The problem here is just `whittakerM` .

Comment: @Abolfazl: In your question you are using the function. This is the only `whittakerM` i know: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/whittakerm.html so I assumed you are using this function. Which function is your code supposed to use?

Comment: May I could not explain well. `WhittakerM` is supposed to be used and it's derivative. So I tried to use `syms` and `diff`, but it doesn't work for this function. I think it's better to use `Mathematica`. Symbolic calculation is cumbersome in `Matlab`.

Comment: I think my Matlab (V 7.6) has a problem with symbolic toolbox. I see the same error in evaluating the codes in that page of Mathworks.

Comment: @Abolfazl: That's not a bug, since Mathworks aquired Mupad the symbolic toolbox was heavily extended. Check your local documentation for working examples.

Comment: @Abolfazl: Matlab 7.6 (i.e., R2008a) is very old. You should always indicate that you're using such an old version in any questions. And you shouldn't be looking at the documentation that you find online with Google. As @Daniel pointed out, the symbolic functions have changed a lot (I believe that `WhittakerM` and `WhittakerW` were added in R2012a). Either use `doc` and `help` within Matlab or used the [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2008a/helpdesk.html) online.